# Почему не работает изменение и удаление в SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, транзакции

Пишу код на Python и SQLite. В двух функциях мне нужно сделать удаление и обновление данных соответственно. Код на Python отлично работает, а вот алгоритм на SQLite не работает, так как никаких изменений в базе данных не происходит. Можно ли как-то исправить проблему?

```
def dell(self):
    for y in range(1, self.kol + 1):
        exec('if self.checkBox_{}.isChecked():\n\t'.format(y) +\
             'self.checkBox_{}.setCheckState(False)\n\t'.format(y) +\
             'self.gridLayout_1.removeWidget(' + 'self.widget_{})'.format(y) +\
             'or self.gridLayout_2.removeWidget(' + 'self.widget_{})\n\t'.format(y) + \

             'cur = self.con.cursor()\n\t' + \
             'sql = """DELETE FROM Задачи WHERE Название = ?"""\n\t' +\
             'rezult = cur.execute(sql, ("self.widget_{}".format(y),))\n\t' +\

             'self.widget_{}.hide()\n\t'.format(y) + \
             
             'self.kol -= 1\n\t' +\
             'self.kol_1 -= 1')

def yes(self):
    for i in range(1, self.kol + 1):
        exec('if self.checkBox_{}.isChecked():\n\t'.format(i) +\
             'self.widget_{}.setStyleSheet(self.green)\n\t'.format(i) +\
             'self.checkBox_{}.setCheckState(False)\n\t'.format(i) +\
             'cur = self.con.cursor()\n\t' +\
             'sql = """UPDATE Задачи SET Статус = ? WHERE ID = ?"""\n\t' +\
             'rezult = cur.execute(sql, (str(self.green), str(i)))')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`con.commit()` забыли

функция сохраняет текущую транзакцию в БД